# Ruby - why doesn't for_each not do the lower case requested? yield/self issue?

Tags: ruby, yield, self

The other converts work, what do I need to do to get D) working ok.  Ultimately D) will be a cipher but I want to just get it working for each character for any function (downcase being an example) initially.  The grouping into 5 character buckets is part of the cipher code I am developing.

```
def keystream_converter(message, conversion)
  case conversion.downcase
    when 'lower_case'
      message.upcase
    when 'upper_case'
      message.downcase
    when 'special'
      message.each_char { |ltr| ltr.downcase }
    else
      'invalid_conversion'
  end
end

initial_src =  "I see Ruby going 100 years!!"
test_string = (initial_src.delete('^a-zA-Z') +"X"*(initial_src.length % 5)).scan(/.{5}/).to_s.upcase
lower = keystream_converter(test_string, 'lower_case')
upper = keystream_converter(test_string, 'upper_case')
special = keystream_converter(test_string, 'special')
#
puts "A) - " + initial_src
puts "B) - " + upper
puts "C) - " + lower
puts "D) - " + special
```

Output:

```
A) - I see Ruby going 100 years!!
B) - ["iseer", "ubygo", "ingye", "arsxx"]
C) - ["ISEER", "UBYGO", "INGYE", "ARSXX"]
D) - ["ISEER", "UBYGO", "INGYE", "ARSXX"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String#each_char yields substrings of length 1 of the original string. If you change these substrings (even with `downcase!` and not a non-mutating `downcase` like in your case), original string will not be affected. If you want to use `each_char` with block, you can do something like this:

```
message.each_char.map(&:downcase).join
```

Comment: Or in other words, `ltr` is a *new* copy of the data, and changing it has no effect on the original.

Comment: +1 Accepted.  This was my favorite in the end, though I liked BaronVonBraun's too (almost as much as I like his name ;) ).

Comment: And this answer was key because it mentions 'yield' and that is a key concept in this question/answer to understanding where control is.  `map` is a great choice for these needs and `.join` (or `+=` or even `<<` as in `result << message.each_char.map(&:downcase).join` to collect them up

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `each_char` returns the original input string and not the result of the block.

For example, if you did this in irb:

```
"A STRING".each_char { |ltr| ltr.downcase }
# => "A STRING"
```

If you want to continue using `each_char`, you should append each of the results to some variable that you can return afterwards, i.e.,

```
# ...
when 'special'
  new_message = ""
  message.each_char { |ltr| new_message += ltr.downcase }
  new_message
else
# ...
```

Comment: +1 I like the very english 1 sentence that this answer begins with.  I basically wish I could combine it with the one from Alex that I accepted as they both make good points.

Comment: This is also the option that I will actually use because it looks easier to now code up a more complicated set of operations than just `'downcase'`

Answer (score 0):

It's strange but anyway. You can change 'special' case to this:

```
message.each_char.map(&:downcase) * ''
```